# Calculate alpha values with torch mean?

Tags: computer-vision, pytorch

I'm trying to calculate the alpha values as explained [here](https://glassboxmedicine.com/2020/05/29/grad-cam-visual-explanations-from-deep-networks/).

I have as argument a tensor with shape `(1, 512, 14, 14)`. To calculate alpha values I need to calculate the average of all dimensions except the channel dimension, so the output will have the shape `(1, k, 1, 1)` which is essentialy `(k,)`.

How can I do this in PyTorch?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could permute the first and second axis to keep the channel dimension on `dim=0`, then flatten all other dimensions, and lastly, take the mean on that new axis:

```
x.permute(1, 0, 2, 3).flatten(start_dim=1).mean(dim=1)
```

Here are the shapes, step by step:

```
>>> x.permute(1, 0, 2, 3).shape
(512, 1, 14, 14)

>>> x.permute(1, 0, 2, 3).flatten(start_dim=1).shape
(512, 1, 196)

>>> x.permute(1, 0, 2, 3).flatten(start_dim=1).mean(dim=1).shape
(512,)
```